# React/Redux async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I have the following piece of code which downloads something from youtube.

```
    var YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader({// some parameters here });

    YD.download('UDzGLMLhy80');

    YD.on("finished", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        return data;
    });

    YD.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log("Error");
    });

    YD.on("progress", function(progress) {
        console.log(progress);
    });
```

I would now like to 'outsource' it into a function and then call this function in my redux action. I have installed redux thunk for this, but I am struggling to translate the redux-thunk examples to my youtube download function above. This is the action I have so far (which is wrong / not working):

```
export const downloadFromYoutube = (download) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    var YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader // ... like above
return YD.download('UDzGLMLhy80').then( //I hard hardcoded this for now
  response => {
    console.log("SUCCESS");
  },
  error => {
    console.log("ERROR");
    throw error
  }
);
```

I think I might be completely off with this actually, but I am not sure how to integrate my function asynchronously. I would also like to use the other funtions ( YD.on("finished") & YD.on("progress") and then dispatch actions accordingly. Sorry if this might be completely off, but a hint in the right direction would be very appreciated!

Edit: I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined(anonymous function) @ index.js:10(anonymous function) @ index.js:11(anonymous function) @ bindActionCreators.js:7onSubmit @ search.component.js:25
...
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: spawn is not a function(…)
```

edit: here is the full action creator now after an edit based on Brandon's answer"

```
var YoutubeMp3Downloader = require('youtube-mp3-downloader');

var YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader({
    "ffmpegPath": "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2/bin/ffmpeg",        // Where is the FFmpeg binary located?
    "outputPath": "/Users/dominik/Coding/youtube-downloader-papa/downloads",    // Where should the downloaded and encoded files be stored?
    "youtubeVideoQuality": "highest",       // What video quality should be used?
    "queueParallelism": 2,                  // How many parallel downloads/encodes should be started?
    "progressTimeout": 2000                 // How long should be the interval of the progress reports
});

export const downloadFromYoutube = (download) => {
    return dispatch => {
      YD.on("finished", data => dispatch({ type: "FINISHED", payload: data }));
      YD.on("error", error => dispatch({ type: "ERROR", payload: error }));
      YD.on("progress", progress => dispatch({ type: "PROGRESS", payload: progress }));

      // dispatch a "starting" action
      // dispatch({ type: "STARTING" });

      // start the download
      YD.download('UDzGLMLhy80');
     }
  };
```

edit: I am calling my action in the following way:
I have a container which implements a 'Search' and which gives this component the function to call whenever the button is pressed:

```
<Search downloadFunction={this.props.downloadFromYoutube}/>
```

Then in the Search component I do:

```
// Import React
import React from 'react';

// Create Search component class
class Search extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     download: ""
   };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
 }
  handleInputChange(evt) {
      this.setState({
          download: evt.target.value
      });
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      /* Do something... */

      this.props.downloadFunction(this.state.download);
  }


  render() {
    // Return JSX via render()
    return (
      <div className="">
        <h1>Youtube Link</h1>
        <input className="form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></input>
        <button className="btn btn-large btn-positive" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Download</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}


// Export Search
export default Search
```

Comment: What is "not working" about it? What did you expect that didn't happen? Nothing looks wrong as long as `YD.download` returns a promise, but you don't actually seem to be using `dispatch` to update the redux store, so no noticeable side effects will occur.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if it does return a promise. I update my question with the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
export const downloadFromYoutube = download => dispatch => {

    const YD = new YoutubeMp3Downloader // ... like above

    // hook up event handlers to dispatch redux actions on activity
    YD.on("finished", data => dispatch({ type: "FINISHED", payload: data }));
    YD.on("error", error => dispatch({ type: "ERROR", payload: error });
    YD.on("progress", progress => dispatch({ type: "PROGRESS", payload: progress }));

    // dispatch a "starting" action
    dispatch({ type: "STARTING" });

    // start the download
    YD.download(download);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Implementing this, I get `Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` & dispatch is not defined: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined`

Comment: you'll need to post how you are using this `downloadFromYoutube` action creator.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? where i call it? or the action creator file itself?

Comment: how do you call it and/or dispatch it

Comment: I edited my original question, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: It is possible you've not configured the `redux-thunk` middleware correctly, based on the errors you are getting.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so, as I have tested it with a timeout function which seemed to work fine. Not sure what else it could be now!